# How to get space between following output

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select replace(substring(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'),100),13,
LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))), ' +05:30','')
```

I am getting output=> 4:06PM

but I want  output=> 4:06 PM

how can I get this output??

Answer (score 1):

Use this `SELECT replace(substring(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'),100), 18,0,' '),13,LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))), ' +05:30','');`

instead of

```
select replace(substring(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30 '),100),13,
LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))),' +05:30',' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select replace(substring(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30 '),100),13,
LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))),' +05:30',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will give you the expected output.

```
SELECT replace(substring(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar,SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'),100), 18, 0, ' '),13,LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))), ' +05:30','');
```

output: 4:22 PM

Answer (score 0):

You can use stuff

```
select STUFF(replace(substring(CONVERT(varchar(50),SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30'),100),13, LEN(CONVERT(varchar,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),100))), ' +05:30',''),6,0,' ')
```

It will stuff a space at the 6th position replacing 0 characters.